# Updating a file fails before Process execution

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am starting a VBScript via C# application. Before starting, I programmatically change some content of the VBScript: Exchanging a placeholder keyword with a computer hostname.
The VBScript executes but uses the placeholder keyword instead of the computer hostname. However, when stopping the code right infront of Process.Start() I can see that the VBScript was successfully modified and saved, containing the computer hostname.
I also tried with adding a Thread.Sleep before execution, but it did not help.

It worked before, I updated some unrelated content on the program and now it fails to work for most of the time. When I use the debugger, sometimes the VBScript is loaded with the correct content. But the final program fails almost all the time.

Any suggesstions what this could be?

Here is the code of the C# process execution:

```cs
if (boEditStartupFileFirst)
{
    string[] stFileContent = File.ReadAllLines(stFullPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < stFileContent.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            stFileContent[i] = stFileContent[i].Replace("NAME", stHostname);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    File.Delete(stFullPath);

    StreamWriter swWriter = new StreamWriter(stFullPath, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < stFileContent.Length; i++)
    {
        swWriter.WriteLine(stFileContent[i]);
    }
    swWriter.Close();
}
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = stFullPath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = stArgs;
p.Start();
```

Here is the content of the VBScript:

```vb
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "regedit"

WScript.Sleep 500 

WshShell.SendKeys "%DM"
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys "NAME"
WScript.Sleep 200
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

What the VBScript does: Open RegEdit and connect to remote computer.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer the question without seeing your code?

Comment: Woops, my bad! Edited the code into the question.

Comment: Where are you setting the `boEditStartupFileFirst` ? The code shown is working for me with a simple `msgbox`  `vbs` file. You might need to show the `vbscript` file too. Also, add the `c#` tag since that is also related.

Comment: The code shown is inside a method of a class. The caller overloads the bool switch.

Comment: `The caller overloads the bool switch` <---  so if it is not switched correctly, the vbs file wont be changed. Can you comment out that check (temporarily) and try?

Comment: Wow, I think I found the issue thanks to your hint. After Process.Start() I execute a method to change the VBScript again, replacing the computer name with the NAME placeholder.
When outcommenting this, the script works...
But why does that happen since I the start of the process happens before the script gets changed back?

Comment: You might need this: [Process.Exited Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hm I had another workaround. Instead of adding more event handlers, I simply checked and replaced the whole line in the VBScript instead of the keyword. This way I don't need to revert the changes after execution and on the next run the whole line will be replaced containing the new host name.